# How to copy a csv file from a url to Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, csv, url

Is there any way to use `copy` command for batch data import and read data from a url. For example, `copy` command has a syntax like :

```
COPY sample_table
FROM 'C:\tmp\sample_data.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

What I want is not to give a local path but a url. Is there any way?

Comment: No, COPY does not support this. But you could first download the file using a procedural language like plpython or plperl

Comment: Yes, you have right. Just with python or php I will download the files and then make the copy. Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward, provided you have an appropriate command-line tool available:

```
COPY sample_table FROM PROGRAM 'curl "http://www.example.com/file.csv"'
```

Since you appear to be on Windows, I think you'll need to install [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/download.html#Win32) or [wget](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm#download) yourself. There is an example using wget on Windows [here](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/325-Using-wget-directly-from-PostgreSQL-using-COPY-FROM-PROGRAM.html) which may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is

```
cat $file |
    tail -$numberLine |
    sed 's/ / ,/g' |
    psql -q -d $dataBaseName -c "COPY tableName FROM STDIN DELIMITER ','"
```

You can insert a `awk` between `sed` and `psql` to add missing column.
Interesting if already you know what to put in the missing column.

```
awk '{print $0" , "'info_about_missing_column'"\n"}'
```

I have done that and it works and faster than `INSERT`.

Comment: thank you
can you delete my post because it did not match the question asked?